# Large list retrieval in SharePoint list failing 4-10 times before working (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, caml

I need to copy items between lists (adding more stuff to each item so cant use flow), I am experiencing a error where if the source list is greater than 100 items, the script terminates at the query into the source list (first thing to happen on button click), for like 4-10 times then it works.

I am using promises to make sure everything happens in order but that doesn't seem to be the issue, but instead the query failing, in the first step in the promise structure.

Its not the rowlimit in the query, as that is set to a 1000, and the row count is around 200.

Here is an example code that works fine with small number of items but requires multiple runs when both lists contain about 100 items:

```
<head>
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>

    function update() {
        console.log("1")
  var dfd = $.Deferred(function () {
    var updateBtnCLientContextForSourceList = 
      new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var getSourceList = updateBtnCLientContextForSourceList
        .get_web()
        .get_lists()
        .getByTitle("SourceList");
    var camlQueryForSourceList = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQueryForSourceList.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>' +
      '<Value Type=\'Number\'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query><RowLimit>4000</RowLimit></View>');
    var SourceListtStore = getSourceList.getItems(camlQueryForSourceList);
    updateBtnCLientContextForSourceList.load(SourceListtStore);
    updateBtnCLientContextForSourceList.executeQueryAsync(
      function () {
        dfd.resolve(SourceListtStore);
      },
      function (sender, args) {
        dfd.reject(args);
      }
    );
  });
         console.log("2")
  return dfd.promise();
}

acadcount = 0;

function check() {
  update()
  .then(
    function (SourceListtStore) {
         console.log("3")
      acadcount = SourceListtStore.get_count()
         console.log("4")
      var dfd = $.Deferred(
        function () {
          var updateBtnCLientContextForWeeksAllocated = 
            SP.ClientContext.get_current();
          var getWeeksAllocated = 
            updateBtnCLientContextForWeeksAllocated
              .get_web()
              .get_lists()
              .getByTitle("Weeks Allocated");
          var camlQueryForWeeksAllocated = new SP.CamlQuery();
          camlQueryForWeeksAllocated.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>' +
            '<Value Type=\'Number\'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query><RowLimit>1000</RowLimit></View>');
          var weeksAllocatedListStore = 
            getWeeksAllocated.getItems(camlQueryForWeeksAllocated);
          updateBtnCLientContextForWeeksAllocated.load(weeksAllocatedListStore);
          updateBtnCLientContextForWeeksAllocated.executeQueryAsync(
            function () {
              dfd.resolve(weeksAllocatedListStore);
            },
            function (sender, args) {
              dfd.reject(args);
            }
          );
        }
      );
         console.log("5")
      return dfd.promise()
    }
  ).then(
    function (waListStore) {
         console.log("6")
      if (waListStore.get_count() === acadcount) {
           console.log("7")
        alert("All items have been copied")
      }
      else {
           console.log("8")
        alert("Please try again")
      }
    }
  );
}

    </script>


</head>

<body>
    <button onClick="check()">Check</button>


</body>
```

- stage 2=just before the return of the source list's query result
- stage 5=just before the return of the weeks allocated list's query
  result

**source list: 2 items, Weeks allocated:3 items**

- first & second run: up to 8(completed)

**Source list: 109 items, Weeks allocated:1 item**

- First run: up to 2
- 2,3: up to 5
- 4: up to 2
- 5-8: up to 5
- 9:up to 8(completed)

**Source list:109 items, weeks allocated:100 items**

- first 33 runs: up to 5
- 34:up to 8(completed)

So am i correct in assuming that, when script fails, the promise.return is running before the .resolve is completed? if so how can i get around this?

Comment: How does it fail? Does it produce an error? Does it take to long and the browser asks you to terminate the script?

Comment: @HMR the page simply reloads, i found by debugging that it sometimes reloads just after the first query...my assumption is that SP is set up so any error causes the script to terminate, and page reload

Comment: You could try to check "preserve log" in console and unselect clear entries on navigate in edge. In Chrome the preserve log is hidden under the settings icon and checkbox with preserve log is available under network. Pause on unhandled errors is available in Chrome under sources looks like a traffic sign with pause icon and a checkbox "Pause on caught exceptions". Maybe add a `window.onbeforeunload` with a `debugger` statement and inspect the stack.

Comment: @HMR already tried that bud, there are no related errors (though weirdly it does go to the older version of the script and that throws couple errors but those errors occur even when everything works so am guessing I can look into that particular issue later)

Comment: @HMR added a example code if it helps

Comment: I formatted the code a bit, maybe you can add some console.log statements in there and identify where it leaves the current page

Comment: @HMR please see edit

Comment: What browser are you using? If not IE, have you tried to remove the promises and run it on IE? Thought process being ClientContext acting differently in different browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page was reloading before JS had a chance to execute completely with a large number of items, disabled refresh on button click and it now works fine.